ReactNative -- Button keeps exceeding specified horizontal width of parent view
import { StyleSheet,
        Text,
        View, 
        SafeAreaView, 
        Platform,
        StatusBar,
        TextInput} from 'react-native';

import FontAwesomeIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';

import { Button } from '@rneui/themed';



export default function App() {
  return (

    <SafeAreaView style={styles.AndroidSafeArea}>
    
      <StatusBar
        backgroundColor="black"
        barStyle="light"
      />


      <View style = {styles.topBar}>
        <View style={{
          display: 'flex',
          flexDirection: 'row',
          alignItems: 'flex-start',
          width: '95%'
        }}>
          <FontAwesomeIcon 
            name ='navicon'
            size={25}
            color='#fff'
          />
          <Text style = {{
            fontSize: 20,
            color: 'white',
            paddingLeft: 10}}>
            Jotfit
          </Text>
        </View>

        <View style={{
          display: 'flex',
          flexDirection: 'row',
          width: '95%',
          alignItems: 'center',
          marginTop: '3%'
        }}>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.seachBarStyle}
            placeholder='Search exercises...'
          />

          <Button
              buttonStyle={{
                borderRadius: 10,
              }}
              icon={{
                name: "search",
                color: "black"
              }}
            type='solid'
            color='white'
          />
        </View>
      </View>


      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>use SF Pro Font22</Text>
      </View>

   
      
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    
  },
  topBar: {
    height: '14%',
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  header: {
    width: '95%',
    height: '90%',
    backgroundColor: 'black'
  },
  AndroidSafeArea: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    paddingTop: Platform.OS === "android" ? 10 : 0
  },
  seachBarStyle: {
    width: '85%',
    height: '100%',
    borderRadius: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 8,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    marginRight: '1.5%'
  }
  
});


Here is what the above code renders to:
how it looks right now
In this section I specify that the width should be 95%
<View style={{
          display: 'flex',
          flexDirection: 'row',
          width: '95%',
          alignItems: 'center',
          marginTop: '3%'
        }}>

However, I notice that the left and right margins are not equal. Changing the width of the button within the buttonStyle makes the icon partially hidden. Currently, the button keeps exceeding the 95% centered margin, making the view look slightly off.
How do I make it nice and centered with equal amounts of spacing on the left and right?
This is what I am aiming for:
Notice how it is equidistant in terms of the left and right margins
desired outcome
I was hoping that the button would auto align itself. Instead it seems to go over.
In fact, when I increase the width % of the text input in "searchBarStyle" it will push the button over the screen.
This is what I mean:
button now out of screen
I briefly tried "flexWrap", "flexShrink" etc but could not get the desired results.
Any help would be much appreciated

I reproduced your code and everything seemed fine. The same as your desired outcome.

Is it possible that it is just rendering weird? I could have sworn that the right and left margins were different @Nima

Try to reproduce the code in Snack: https://snack.expo.dev

I would try justifyContent: 'center' on the wrapping element ( I guess this should be the topBar), so whatever is inside of it will center it and the left-right margins should be equal.
